# Increase numbers by one in merged cells

Tags: macos, numbers, iwork

My question is very related to this https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3204532.

I just want to do the same but in merged cells, as in the picture below. Is it possible?

I see no fill handle here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill handles do not operate with merged cells. You can use a formula to achieve the same effect.

Insert the following in these cells:

- A1 (the merged cells A1 and A2)

  ```
  1
  ```
- A3 (the merged cells A3 and A4)

  ```
  =A1+1
  ```

Copy and paste A3 for the rest of the column.

The following animation shows the entire procedure:

[image]